# Complex table with many rows and values

Tags: usability

1. I have multiple list values , areas of analysis and impact over time as below also impact recovery values
   [image]

Please suggest on my a better way and easy to user to use than the one I made.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a table?

It could be two-step navigation: a list of Analysis Areas ("Financial", "Customer", etc) and maybe those Inpact Figures summary, and then, when an item in the list is clicked, there's [a proper form](https://carbondesignsystem.com/patterns/forms-pattern/) for Impact Over Time with labels and inputs.

This way it's much less cluttered, less overwhelming, the user has distinct context to work in and it solves a ton of other problems: responsivity, it makes it easier to use without mouse, and so on. Just make sure it's not ambiguous which Analysis Area is user filling up the info for.

Mind you, it doesn't have to be "Navigation" navigation:

- You can open the form in a modal;
- You can do a master-detail, where you pick from the list on a panel and to right of that, the form fills up with the selected info;
- Or anything other that fits the pattern "choose the area - fill up info for that area"

Answer (score 0):

You could think of the use-cases for which the table is relevant. So which kind of user wants to use this table to fulfill which kind of job. Then based on that you know which parts of the data are necessary to be displayed, depending on the user and his job.
This could be handled via buttons at the top of the table. When clicked, they only show what is relevant in this case.
Of course you can always also implement a "Show all" button which shows the original table with all the data.